# Matrix multiplication with custom function

Tags: c#, math.net

Using the `Matrix<double>` from Mathdotnet.Numerics, I am willing to apply a custom aggregating function for each cell of the resulting matrix of a multiply operation.

For instance, on a 2x2 matrix:

[image]

My will is to have a **specific `f` function** (the one above, shown as example, is the default matrix/vector multiplication).

Is there an existing method in the Matrix world that takes such a `Func<Vector<double>, Vector<double>, double>` argument?

Comment: You tried anything ?

Comment: @Navoneel Yes I mainly tried the `Map2(..)`method but it does not exactly what I need. It passes just the matching cells, not the whole row + column.

Comment: Your question has been resolved?

Comment: @FoggyFinder not yet. Seems there is no straight forward (aka optimized) way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your diagram, it looks like you're trying to get the dot product of two vectors.

MathDotNet provides a function for DotProduct. It would look like this:

```
Vector<double> v1;
Vector<double> v2;
double result = v1.DotProduct(v2);
```

And it returns the sum of `v1[i]*v2[i]` for all `i`.

See the [documentation](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/Vector.htm) here.

If you would like to create your own function to manipulate two vectors and return a double, that would be fairly easy.

```
double MyNewFunction(Vector v1, Vector v2) 
{
    // your code here, as an example here is the matrix multiplication
    double returnValue;
    if (v1.Count!= v2.Count) 
    {
        // process error
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< v1.Count; i++) 
    {
        returnValue += v1.Item[i] * v2.Item[i];
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I'm willing to apply my own `f` method. Not the default one, that is, indeed, the `dot`as you wrote (or simply put: the matrix mulitplication). It seems my question was not well phrased (question updated for disambiguation).

Comment: @Askolein I updated my answer, I hope that answers your question.

Comment: The question is about finding a way to use your `MyNewFunction` in a Matrix method. As a parameter. Look at Matrix.Map2(...). It's an example of usage. But I need a equivalent that matches 2 vectors (row + column) instead of just two cells.